# jQuery add text (on entire table width) below row when it was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add some very large text below the row when row was clicked, so that it's width  would be entire row width. Now it is only below first column of the row.

HTML:

```
<table id="accordion" class="table">
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
  <script>
    $("tr").on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).after("<p>SOME very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  long text!</p>");
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: how about using `colspan="3"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? I just used colspan

```js
$("tr").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).after("<tr><td colspan=3><p>SOME very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  long text!</p></td></tr>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="accordion" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should wrap `td` in `tr` to make it valid HTML

Comment: Good point. really can't remember the last time I had to use colspan, or rowspan for that matter. I always end up wanting to add another column (or 5) later on, and re-order things. The colspan just gets in my way :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create another row and set its colspan to 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$('#accordion').on("click", 'tr', function(e) {
    $(this).next('tr').text("<td></td><td>SOME very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  long text!</td><td></td>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `<tr><td>` elements to append in your table. And to occupy the 100% of the table you need to use `colspan`

```
$("tr").on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).after($('<tr />').html($('<td colspan="3"/>').html('A very long  text')));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work but the the more text you add the more width will be added to your table stretching the columns.

```
  <script>
    $("tr").on("click", function(e) {
        $(this).after("<tr><td colspan='3'>SOME very very  very very  very very  very very  very very  long text!</td></tr>");
    });
  </script>
```