# dynamically add a table row with an onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to pass the "id" parameter to the "onclick" function?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
             {
             var row = table.insertRow(0);
             row.onclick = (function() {
             var id = items[i].id;// here!
             });
             var cell = row.insertCell(0);
             cell1.innerHTML = items[i].title;
             }
```

When I click on row it says that items is undefined and I understand why, so I'm asking about other ways to get id parameter in onclick function.
Also I'm thinking to keep id value in hidden cell

Comment: we don't know what items is, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id) question helps

Comment: This question doesn't make sense... should look into clarifying..

Comment: "items" is an array of objects with id and title properties

Comment: Try a console.log(items[i]) and show us the output, could also help.

Comment: If you can use jQuery then here is the answer to your question. [stackoverflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542663/jquery-add-text-on-entire-table-width-below-row-when-it-was-clicked/26542775#26542775)

Comment: what should on click do ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. It should have the id of current row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using jQuery, I'd do something along these lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    row.setAttribute("data-myID", items[i].id);
    row.onclick = (function() {
        console.log(this.getAttribute("data-myID"));
    });
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    //cell1.innerHTML = items[i].title;
}
```

full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hztkzcya/